# Как получить данные о таблицах из бд ms sql?

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server

Здравствуйте, такая проблема. При запуске программы я хотел бы получать информацию о всех таблицах в бд (имя таблицы, кол-во и имена их стобцов).
Как это сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого есть представления в схеме sys:
`select * from sys.tables` - таблицы
`select * from sys.columns` - столбцы
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189783.aspx - другие представления.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```